# How to open Neshan app to show routing in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, routes, neshan, neshan-map

I need to open the [Neshan](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.rajman.neshan.traffic.tehran.navigator&hl=en&gl=US) Application (map application like `Google-Map`).
This is my code:

```
if (UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(NSURL(string:"comgooglemaps://")!)) {
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(
        NSURL(string:"comgooglemaps://?saddr=&daddr=\(place.latitude),\(place.longitude)&directionsmode=driving")!
    )
} else {
    NSLog("Can't use comgooglemaps://");
}
```

This is not work! what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to declare the URL schemes, you want to use in your Info.plist. Use the key LSApplicationQueriesSchemes for that.

Add neshan key to LSApplicationQueriesSchemes.

[image]

Then using this snippet swift code to open the app with their custom schema.

```
if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(URL(string: "neshan://")!) {
     
      // neshan is installed.
      let urlStr = String(format: "neshan://")
      UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL(string: urlStr)!)
   } else {
        // neshan is not installed.
 }
```